# How to implement an efficient review function in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm setting up a database for a website I want to create. I've learned much about SQL in my school, but I've encountered a problem when creating the ERD for my project.
I want to implement a review function on my website where products can be reviewed by others.
Now to my problem: How do I implement reviews in my database? I've thought about

reviewID | personthatgetsreviewedID | personthatreviewedID | reviewtext

Is it legit to do a giant review table or should I split it up somehow?

Comment: Your table seems reasonable.

Comment: SQL tables can be long. Don't subdivide it lengthwise or you will run into problems like (x in list)? per table. The width of a table can be quite different depending on its purpose, although always keep normalization in mind when designing it initially.

Comment: Time to read a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.) Dozens of published academic information modeling & DB design textbooks are online free in pdf. stanford.edu has a free online course. (But asking for resources outside SO is off-topic.) PS This is too broad. It's also not clear. What does "implement" mean? What is "giant"? PS There is no point in worrying re things you notice when you are uninformed/inexperienced.

Comment: Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show the steps of your work following your textbook with justification & explain re the first place you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you would explain your purpose a bit more clearly.
However, I think, a single review table would be adequate if managed properly. And, I think it would be great to add one more column such as "publishStatus" to filter the review or grant control to admin panels to filter and publish the reviews. However, this is optional, it depends upon the requirements and your priority.